# JS Define Full Range of Printable Characters

Tags: javascript, string, text, replace

I am using a JS string to fade in a full paragraph of text. The string is:

```
$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\xFF]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
```

Basically the text slowly fades in (easing: "easeInOutQuad"). Everything is working fine aside from the period and quotation marks in the text. They appear immediately.

I'm guessing I'm simply missing the characters for . and " in the range [^\x00-\xFF]. I cannot, though, for the life of me work out how to add . and " to that range. Any assistance much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Your code doesn't show the fading stuff, it only shows the part that puts each character in its own `<span>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have runnable code you can show it using the Snippet tool in the editor below or in jsfiddle, codepen etc.
[Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

I am not a regular expression expert.
I [used](https://regex101.com/) to do some testing.

([^\x00-\xFF]|\w)
I'm reading this as any char in range x00-xFF 
OR
a Word character

\w means Word character

==============

how about [\W|\w] ? as a first step   --Non Word or Word character

Comment: Perfect, my friend. That solved the issue completely; all periods and quotations marks are now being included in the JS script. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer!